# Why does this for loop behave differently depending on how it is compiled?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, vulkan

I made an error while writing a method based on the [vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers) that I didn't catch until I changed my build. If you read below, you will see the erroneous method as well as the corrected method. The bug itself isn't what I'm asking about, but for completeness: the issue was that I had swapped the variables that determined the length of the loops. For some reason, when compiling and linking the program all in one step via GCC, the method returned true anyway, even though it should have returned false due to my mistake. When I later changed my build to compile files into objects separately, then link them in a later step, this method returned false as it should have.

Q: Why did the for loop behave differently in different builds?

Info:

```
### "All in one" GCC command used:
gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(NAME) $(SRC_DIR)/\*.c $(LDFLAGS)


### commands used for the multi-step build:
compile step (run per-file):
gcc $(CFLAGS) -c -o $(SRC_DIR)/object1.c $(INCLUDES_FLAGS)

link step:
gcc $(CFLAGS) -o output $(objects) $(LDFLAGS)

Relevant flags used:
CFLAGS = -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror=return-type -pthread -g -O0
LDFLAGS = -lc -lm -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -lcglm
```

Incorrect method (swapped the hardcoded constant LAYER_COUNT with the layerCount that is found at runtime):

```c
const char* validationLayers[] = {
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation",
};
const uint32_t LAYER_COUNT = (sizeof(validationLayers) / sizeof(validationLayers[0]));

...

bool checkValidationLayerSupport() {
    uint32_t layerCount;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, NULL);

    VkLayerProperties availableLayers[layerCount];
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers);

    const char* layerName;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < layerCount; i++) {
        layerName = validationLayers[i];
        bool layerFound = false;

        VkLayerProperties layerProperties;
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < LAYER_COUNT; j++) {
            layerProperties = availableLayers[j];
            if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0) {
                layerFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!layerFound) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Corrected method:

```c
const char* validationLayers[] = {
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation",
};
const uint32_t LAYER_COUNT = (sizeof(validationLayers) / sizeof(validationLayers[0]));

...

bool checkValidationLayerSupport() {
    uint32_t layerCount;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, NULL);

    VkLayerProperties availableLayers[layerCount];
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers);

    const char* layerName;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < LAYER_COUNT; i++) {
        layerName = validationLayers[i];
        bool layerFound = false;

        VkLayerProperties layerProperties;
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < layerCount; j++) {
            layerProperties = availableLayers[j];
            if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0) {
                layerFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!layerFound) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I expected the method to have consistent behavior when compiled and linked in one step or when compile and linked as separate steps. I determined that it is/was not an issue with my environment or with the VulkanSDK by running the above code under a clean install and getting the same behavior. The CFLAGS and LDFLAGS variables are also the same in both situations.

Comment: If your bug is causing out-of-bound access in the array, then the behavior is undefined and no consistency should be expected.

Comment: Your functions are badly written. You do not use any parameters and only work on the global variables. It is a very bad approach. Vulcan tutorial definitely does not advice it. If the program behaves differently depending on hardware/compiler/compile options it is an obvious sign of ***Undefined Behavior***.

Comment: When a program has undefined behavior, it's very common that changes that seem irrelevant will have other side effects. For instance, adding or removing a `printf()` may change whether the program crashes.

Comment: When trying to understand why undefined behavior is weird, it's worth (re)reading the stolen-hotel-room-key analogy:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/131930

Comment: side: `LAYER_COUNT` should be `size_t`

Comment: I understand that it is undefined behavior, but I ran and rebuilt this code several dozen times across several days and several reboots. I was under the impression that undefined behavior is generally erratic and will not normally do the same thing across separate builds and runs.  Am I incorrect in this assumption? Did I just luck out and my crappy code happened to access the same area of memory repeatedly for several days?

Comment: You are incorrect. A program having undefined behavior can even work correctly for years, or forever, because even though it is undefined it happens not to affect the functionality in these specific circumstances. But it can surely blow in your face once the circumstances are changing.

Comment: I see. Thank you for correcting me. I'm new to SO, do I need to mark an answer or does that happen automatically after some amount of time?

Comment: No one have posted a formal answer yet, all these are just comments.

Comment: Welcome to SO, OP, if you keep writing clear questions and listening carefully to answers you'll get lots of support here.   Is there a canonical UB question we can mark as a dup, somebody?